# Can you create a link that uses current URL dynamically using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a custom twitter share button that dynamically pulls the page you are on and shares it to twitter.  Here is where im at:

```
<a href="" onclick="window.location = 'http://twitter.com/home?status=' + document.write(document.URL); return false" target="_blank"><img src="https://twitter.com/favicons/favicon.ico" style="border:1px solid grey;box-shadow:0 4px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2);border-radius: 3px;padding:2px;" /></a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dSVJf/1/

Comment: Just remove the `document.write` part. You are not editing the current page HTML, you just want to generate the link and go for it.

Comment: Do i need to use <script> tags any where when I do this? For some reason it is not working.

Comment: @Chaddly: It won't work in jsfiddle because Twitter doesn't work inside an iFrame.

Comment: I'm trying this on my local computer: onclick="window.location = 'http://twitter.com/home?status=' + document.URL"

Comment: @Chaddly: `onclick="window.location = 'http://twitter.com/home?status=' + document.URL; return false"`

Comment: Woah, didn't know `document.URL` existed. I've only been using `location.href`.

Comment: @AdamBergmark, [check this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.URL).

Answer (score 0):

Went with this:

onclick="window.open('http://twitter.com/home?status=' + document.URL, '_blank');"

Answer (score 0):

A better solution than only removing `document.write` would be to set the href for users having javascript disabled:

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/home?status=" onclick="this.href += document.URL" target="_blank"><img src="https://twitter.com/favicons/favicon.ico" style="border:1px solid grey;box-shadow:0 4px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2);border-radius: 3px;padding:2px;" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this

**HTML:**

```
<a href="javascript:load_twitter();"><img src="https://twitter.com/favicons/favicon.ico" style="border:1px solid grey;box-shadow:0 4px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2);border-radius: 3px;padding:2px;" /></a>
```

**JS:**

```
function load_twitter() { 
    window.open('http://twitter.com/share?text=Try this&url='+ window.location.href +'&via=atsbyvermouth','','scrollbars=no,menubar=no,height=450,width=650,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no'); 
    return false;
}
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/8nTk5/5/)